# Function with map parameter needs additional arguments?

Tags: c++, dictionary, std-pair

I have this piece of code:

```
std::map< int, std::pair<int, int> > m;
for ( std::vector<Pass*>::const_iterator passIt = it->GetPasses().begin(); passIt != it->GetPasses().end(); ++passIt )
{
    m.insert( std::make_pair((*passIt)->GetType(), (*passIt)->GetAgeRange()) );
}
--> ages.push_back( new std::istringstream(SerializeAges(m)) ); <--
```

The marked line yields this error:

```
undefined reference to `SerializeAges(std::map<int, std::pair<int, int>, std::less<int>, 
 std::allocator<std::pair<int const, std::pair<int, int> > > > const&)'
```

Declaration:

```
 static std::string SerializeAges(const std::map< int, std::pair<int, int> > &ageMap);
```

Definition:

```
inline std::string SerializeAges(const std::map< int, std::pair<int, int> > &ageMap)
{       
}
```

Signatures of other called functions:

```
std::pair<int, int> GetAgeRange() const;
```

I have no idea what goes wrong here.

EDIT: sorry, `Type` is an enum, so what `GetType()` returns is implicitly converted to an int.

Comment: "Undefined reference" implies that the function is missing its definition. Have you defined it? Are you linking with whichever file contains the definition?

Comment: @MikeSeymour yes, it is defined, and I'm linking it.

Comment: Well the compiler disagrees. Perhaps you could show us the definition (leaving out the function body, since that shouldn't matter), so we can check that it matches the declaration? Also, is it a member function?

Comment: @MikeSeymour I added the definition without the body. It's a medthod of a "static class".

Comment: @Simple May I ask why? I have ~20 more methods declared and defined similarly in this class, and everything else works great. Same error after removing, by the way.

Comment: Is the static member function declared in a header and the definition in a .cpp file? In that case you need to remove the `inline`. If this is the case for other functions as well I assume that they are only being used in a single .cpp file.

Comment: Inline functions must be defined in every file that calls them. If you just define it in one source file, then it can only be used in that file. So you can either remove `inline` and leave a single definition in a source file, or move the `inline` definition into a header included wherever the function is called.

Comment: If it's a member (static or otherwise), then you'll have to qualify its name (e.g. `ClassName::SerializeAges) in the definition.

Comment: @MikeSeymour The latter is the case. The header in which the function is declared / defined inline, is indeed included at the place of calling.

Comment: The declaration and definition are both in the header file?

Comment: @MikeSeymour Yes. I knew this was something really stupid. Thanks. `Serializer::` is missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments, it seems that it's a class member. In that case, the definition will need to use the qualified name:

```
inline std::string WhateverTheClassIsCalled::SerializeAges(const std::map< int, std::pair<int, int> > &ageMap)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Without that, the definition declares a separate non-member function with the same name, and the member remains undefined.

Comment: I like these errors. They're my favourite kind; the ones that make you feel especially stupid. :)